# Error returned for function's prototype

Tags: c++, function, prototype

Why must we use prototypes before the `main()` function?

1. I initialize my own function after `main()` and I specify the type of the returning value and type of entering arguments all the same. Why must I do that one more time before `main()`?
2. I thought I could change type of the returning value and type of entering arguments with function's prototype, but I couldn't do it! I got this:

   > /tmp/ccixLbJm.o: In function 'main':
   >   learn.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to 'plusValue(double)'
   >   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

   after

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   double plusValue(double value);

   int main () {           
       cout << plusValue(5.32) << endl;            
   }


   int plusValue (int value){        
       value++;            
       return value;        
   }
   ```

So, why on earth must we use these prototypes if it doesn't let us change returning and entering values and they're all the same specified after `main()`?

Comment: You don't have to use prototypes in C++, btw. But why would you want to change the type and return value later on anyway?? In C, you need to use the prototype so that the compiler knows that something exists before you calling it.

Comment: "Prototype" is a concept from C. C++ doesn't have prototypes; it only has *declarations*.

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought a prototype is the same as a (full) declaration. Are you saying there is a semantic difference between the two? Or are you just saying the c++ language / community avoids use of the term "prototype" altogether and prefers to just stick with "declaration" by convention?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: I'm saying that no such thing exists in C++. In C there are two distinct notions of declaration and prototype.

Comment: @KerrekSB You basically rephrased the earlier statement without adding anything! xD I'll clarify: older versions of c allowed "partial" declarations, i.e. omitting number and type of arguments. Therefore in c, a "prototype" denotes a declaration that is "full", i.e. one that specifies the number and type of arguments. Given "partial" declarations are not a thing in c++, one doesn't need to make the distinction between a prototype and a declaration, therefore we don't bother with the former term at all". Is this what you meant? Or is my understanding flawed and there's a fundamental difference?

Comment: @Muller The use of `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice. See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for why. Furthermore, [there is an insanely high number of bad c++ books out there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list); if your textbook seems to encourage such a practice, get rid of it and get a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function declaration isn't equal with its definition.

```
double plusValue(double value)
```

isn't equal

```
int plusValue (int value)
```

The code should be something like this

```
#include <iostream>

double plusValue(double value); // function declaration

int main () {
    cout << plusValue(5.32) << endl;
}

double plusValue(double value){ //function definition
    value += 1;
    return value;
}
```

Summing up the comments, we have to declare our function before using it. function declaration tells the compiler about function return value and number and type of its arguments. Without these information's, compiler doesn't know how to interact with our function (interact means passing arguments to stack and getting returned value). Function definition also needed, the function definition is function's actual executable body, so you have to define it, but it's not necessary to define it in file you have declared. You can define function in another file or library.

If you don't declare a function and define it, the compiler implicitly declare it for you, some compilers require declaration (or implicit declaration) prior to any usage of that function, so if you want to just define the function without declaring it, you have to put definition before any usage of that function.

As Clliford said, the real benefit of separating function declaration and its definition is separate compile and procedure for different C/C++ files.

Comment: If function declaration must always be as its definition, what is profit of using that declaration? Cause I could just define my function before main without declaration and it works fine.

Comment: declaration tells the compiler function A with argument types a,b,c .. and return value of d exists, the definition could be on this file, another file or even a shared library. function definition is body of executable code. it should have same signature with its declaration

Comment: but why should we tells compiler that function A with its type of return value and types of args exists, if compiler doesn't throw error and everything works fine without definition?

Comment: I mean, this code works fine: <p> </p> `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int plusValue (int value){

 value++;

 return value;

}


int main () {
 
 int val;
 cin >> val;
 cout << plusValue(val) << endl;
 
}`

Comment: we have to tell compiler function declaration, without declaring a function compiler doesn't know how to interact with it. if you define a function without declaring it, the compiler implicitly declare it for you. but some compilers require you to declare/define function without prior usage

Comment: ex. if you move function definition after main function, compiler may warn or error about function declaration.

Comment: @e.jahandar :  While this answer fixes the code error, it does not to answer the question.  You have done that in a subsequent comment - that information should appear in the answer, otherwise it is unclear why this would have been accepted as an answer.

Comment: @e.jahandar please don't encourage newbies to use `using namespace std;`. I know you were just copying from the question, but, the answer might as well follow good programming style!

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow the compiler to parse the code in a single pass, the prototype allows appropriate code generation for the *call* before the full definition is known, because the generation of the call only needs to know the *interface*.

It is not in fact necessary to have the prototype declaration if the definition appears before `main()`; the following is equally valid:

```
#include <iostream>

double plusValue (double value)
{
    return value + 1.0 ;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << plusValue(5.32) << std::endl ;
}
```

The real benefit of prototype declarations is that they allow separate compilation and linking, where a definition may be in a separate translation unit to that in which it is used, with the declaration normally in a header file.

Comment: please don't encourage newbies to use `using namespace std;` :)  (I know you were just copying, but still ... )

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou :  While I agree entirely, addressing that would have meant making changes to the original code that were not relevant to the question in hand and therefore a distraction. However since you have raised the issue, I am happy to edit it.  Your comment may however have been more appropriately applied to the original question or the currently *accepted* answer that also repeats the `using` declaration.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't even spot there was an accepted answer when I wrote this (maybe there wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

The use of function declarations is that you can declare a function that code before the function's definition can call because the compiler already knows what it's return type will be and what arguments it expects. Your code currently tells the compiler that there will be a definition for the function `double plusValue(double value)` later in the code. Then you use that function in `main` so the compiler let's you. It knows the function takes a `double` and that's what you pass. Then after `main` you define a function `plusValue` that takes an `int` and returns an `int`, this is completely different than the declaration you just made. Then the linker tries to find the definition for `double plusValue` and it can't find it and then you get a nice linker error.